# Click a button on a page and information drops down below it?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have an image on my site and I want people to be able to click it and to have information appear below it? Like hidden information so it appears when the image is clicked on but disappears when the image is clicked a second time.

The only part of code so far is just the image code:

```
<img src="info.jpg">
```

Thanks guys!

James

Comment: This is quite a duplicate of your other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209653/how-to-reveal-information-when-clicking-on-a-button-text

Comment: etuardu's answer is right, but if you want to go further and make it pretty you can use some frameworks animations like DOJO offers for example this one: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/fx/wipeIn.html . Its free, easy to use and cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery you can have this code:

```
<img src="info.jpg" onclick="$('#info').toggle()" /><br />
<div id="info" style="display:none">Information about your picture </div>
```

With regular javascript you can do this:

```
<img src="info.jpg" onclick="info();" /><br />
<div id="info" style="display:none">Information about your picture </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function info(){
var currently = document.getElementById('info').getAttribute('style');
    if (currently != 'display:none')
        document.getElementById('info').setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
    else
        document.getElementById('info').setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
};
</script>
```

Of course with regular javascript you have to ensure that it is the only inline style you are setting, or do further parsing of the information.  Also, you may use something other than display block.

Another separate option, that I like to use is a tooltip.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, but when I use this code the rext "Information about your picture" is already shown how can I have it so the text only shows once the image is clicked?

Comment: my bad, I forgot to declare the function in the second one, here's the change add function info(){ *previous code here* }; around the script element.  Otherwise it's self executing and the onclick doesn't work in the regular javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Ingredients for your recipe are the [onclick event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) (javascript) and the [display property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) (css).

Answer (score 1):

Make the image a link using the anchor tag and use div's to show or hide the information. Hope that helped